# Write to online SQL Database using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need to save the data from android into an online SQL database. I made a PHP file for doing the task. I am trying to save the data using GET in a PHP file but it always returns false. Kindly have a look at my code and please help. The file is called using an android application. Tried testing though REST add-ons for browsers.

EDIT : Problem - When I send the data using HTTP GET all I get in return is the JSON result {"result":false}. This means my SQL query does not run properly. I tried running the same code directly in phpMyAdmin and it works.

EDIT : Code corrected.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");

$rrequest_status = $_GET['request_status'];
$rstudent_name = $_GET['student_name'];
$rrequest_to = $_GET['request_to'];
$renrollment_no = $_GET['enrollment_no'];
$rout_date = $_GET['out_date'];
$rout_time = $_GET['out_time'];
$rin_date = $_GET['in_date'];
$rin_time = $_GET['in_time'];
$rrequest_time = $_GET['request_time'];
$rapproved_time = $_GET['approved_time'];
$rvisit_place = $_GET['visit_place'];
$rvisit_type = $_GET['visit_type'];
$rcontact_number = $_GET['contact_number'];


$squery = "INSERT INTO `gatepass_requests` (
`gatepass_number` ,
`request_status` ,
`student_name` ,
`request_to` ,
`enrollment_no` ,
`out_date` ,
`out_time` ,
`in_date` ,
`in_time` ,
`request_time` ,
`approved_time` ,
`approved_by` ,
`visit_place` ,
`visit_type` ,
`contact_number`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  
'".$rrequest_status."', 
'".$rstudent_name."', 
'".$rrequest_to."', 
'".$renrollment_no."', 
'".$rout_date."',   
'".$rout_time."',   
'".$rin_date."',  
'".$rin_time."',  
'".$rrequest_time."', 
NULL,  
'".$rapproved_by."',  
'".$rvisit_place."', 
'".$rvisit_type."', 
'".$rcontact_number."', 
)";


if(mysqli_query($con,$squery)){
      $result['result'] = true;
}else{
      $result['result'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($result);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you experiencing an error when trying insert the information into the database?

Comment: echo your query and run directly into phpmyadmin and check error!!

Comment: As a side note: the code you have there has a major security hole as it can be attacked using sql injection.

Comment: Or use `mysqli_error($con)` to find out what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

*To set the record straight for future readers*.

The fact of the matter here is that you have different/undefined variables for the following used in your VALUES:

- `$rrequest_status`
- `$rrequest_to`
- `$rrequest_time`

But have declared them as, and with an extra "r" and assuming that is your real code and not just a bad paste in your question:

Sidenote: Assuming the GET requests as opposed to POST.

- `$request_status = $_GET['request_status'];`
- `$request_to = $_GET['request_to'];`
- `$request_time = $_GET['request_time'];`

And error reporting would have have signaled undefined variables notices but failed to mention that.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Then you stated this comment in an answer given:

> *"Thank You so much for your reply, I removed it for the time being, but it is not the problem. PHP does allow to have trailing commas so it doesn't matter. – Pradumn Kumar Mahanta"*

Maybe for certain PHP operations, but we're dealing with MySQL here and that alone would have thrown you an exception about the trailing comma for:

- `'".$rcontact_number."',` <<<

In regards to the [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) you're open to, use a prepared statement:

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php (MySQLi_)
- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements (PDO)

Error checking references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (PHP)
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php (MySQLi)

Comment: Thank you sir, for the detailed information. The PHP file that I am using has all the variables correct, all with an extra 'r'. My mistake was that the SQL table for some reason would not take NULL for approved_time column from here, and I was trying to insert NULL in it. In phpMyAdmin it was taking NULL values but the the error I got back finally from mysqli_error($con); stated that it won't. I will be using prepared statements in the final project, this code was just to test the basic insertion and to know the mistakes that I don't want to make there.

Comment: @PradumnKumarMahanta You're most welcome, *cheers* - Stay safe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you used `$con = new mysqli("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");`. So you are following **Object oriented style**. So, you need to follow **Object oriented style** for executing query. Right now you mixed **Object oriented style** & **Procedural style**

Change

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$squery)){
      $result['result'] = true;
}else{
      $result['result'] = false;
}
```

To

```
if($con->query($squery)){
      $result['result'] = true;
}else{
      $result['result'] = false;
}
```

For more info, please have a look here [Object Oriented Style & Procedural Style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply. I tried using what you suggested but it did not solve the issue. I am using the same code in another PHP script and it works. I am only facing the problem in this one.

Comment: Not recommended but they can be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove extra `,` from the insert query.**

```
 '".$rcontact_number."', <-- this one
```

To check what error comes, do following:

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$squery)) {
      $result['result'] = true;
} else {
      $result['result'] = mysqli_error($con); // instead of false, use mysqli_error($con)
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply, I removed it for the time being, but it is not the problem. PHP does allow to have trailing commas so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @PradumnKumarMahanta what was the issue?

Comment: Besides the trailing comma it was undefined variables and made typos for a few of them.

Comment: My mistake was that the SQL table for some reason would not take NULL for approved_time column from here, and I was trying to insert NULL in it. In phpMyAdmin it was taking NULL values but the the error I got back finally from mysqli_error($con); stated that it won't.